# Reading sms comming from a specific port

Tags: android

Hi all I'am trying to read sms body and source from a paricular port. I can read the source number but the sms body is always null. Can someone help me to resolve this?

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
    Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
    if (extras != null) {
        // Get received SMS Array
        Object[] smsExtra = (Object[]) extras.get(SMS_EXTRA_NAME);
        for (int i = 0; i < smsExtra.length; i++) {
            SmsMessage sms;
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                String format = intent.getExtras().getString("format");
                sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) smsExtra[i], format);
            } else
                 sms = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) smsExtra[i]);
              System.out.println(sms.getOriginatingAddress());
              System.out.println(sms.getMessageBody());

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Whats the value of `SMS_EXTRA_NAME`?

Comment: Hi  Daniel Luque thanks for your reply the value of  SMS_EXTRA_NAME is "pdus"

Comment: `createFromPdu` return an array of SmsMessage, but your declaration is incorrect. Try with `SmsMessage[] sms = new SmsMessage[smsExtra.length];`

Comment: Ok let me try this and i will come back to you

Comment: Hi Daniel the createFromPdu retrun a SmsMessage not an array of  SmsMessage

Comment: You are right! In that case, do you have the READ_SMS manifest permission and do you ask user to accept the permission in runtime?

Comment: Yes ofcourse here are permissions:            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
            <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>

Comment: I can read the sms source number but i can't do it for the body